# Individual user settings in ASP.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I need to have bunch of settings for each user. Theese settings are same for all the users but every user can change their values. I'm looking for a good approach to create such an infrastructure. My best guess for now is table with all the settings in DB and a table with SettingId UserId and value. Not sure this is the best way tho.

Comment: What is wrong with the table approach? Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's opinion based

Comment: I don't see anything wrong but my uncertainty comes from many articles I have read these days suggesting new json file where I should store those things,

Answer (score -2):

In .net core , you can also use appsettings.json to store such configuration like as below:

```
    {
     "Users": {
              "Arun": {
                       "Id": "ArunId",
                       "Name": "ArunName"
                      },
              "Santa": {
                       "Id": "SantaId",
                       "Name": "SantaName"
                     }
              }
    }
```

you can directly convert these to strong type object with help of IConfiguration interface like below :

_configuration.GetSection("Users")

Comment: OP stated "but every user can change their values".

Comment: So you are suggesting changing appsettings in runtime? And what will happen if your application is redeployed?

Comment: we can write end user changes value back to configuration file it can be json , xml ,ini ,etc. user related configuration file will not be change during deployment.

Comment: So you will need an extra config file specially for this settings which you will use as table in database? And handle backups separately, not with usual DB backups?  And what about your app being deployed to some cloud infrastructure?

Comment: You are assuming about scenario, users ask what is the option available for storing user specific configuration. The way i shared it is one way, there are multiple options available. solution vary according to situation. so we should not be hypothetical. plz don't discourage someone if we can not encourage..

Comment: @user13422309 the OP question is opinion based, and so, off topic in SO